# How to get items from list<classname> those are not in list<int> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have two list

1. `List<ObjectData>`  and
2. `List<int>`

Class `ObjectData` contains:- ID, Fname, LName

`List<int>` contains the IDs.

How to Get Items from `List<ObjectData>` those are not in `List<int>`.

```
List<int> lstPractitionerID = //get list 
    var lstfianl = lstPractitionerPC
              .Select(a=>a.ID).ToList().Except(lstPractitionerID).ToList();
```

but this return only ID, I need whole object data class

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What problems are you having with those existing implementations?

Answer (score 7):

you can use linq with a lambda expression:

```
List<ObjectData> objDat;
List<int> integers;

objDat.Where(o=>!integers.Contains(o.ID));
```

Comment: This would be correct if the method names started with upper case, and look better if the variable names started with lower case.  Also `o.ID` instead of just `o`.

Comment: Contains except int, not list<int>?

Comment: the `o` in the lambda expression represents the iterator on `objDat`, so you check for each `o` if it is contained in `integers`

Comment: It should be `!integers.Contains(o.ID)`.

Comment: it gives me The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.Contains(int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @juharr yea sorry, i wrote that before he updated his question :p

Comment: @Piyush try now, it missed the ID part

Answer (score 2):

This should get you what you want:

```
 List<ObjectData> lObj = new List<ObjectData>();//Create your ObjectData List here
 List<int> lInt = new List<int>();//Create your int List here
 List<ObjectData> resultList = lObj.Where(o => !lInt.Contains(o.ID)).ToList();
```

Comment: If it makes you feel better, someone downvoted me too xD, but your answer is good, you got my upvote.

Comment: I up voted your question to nullify the down vote. Really don't understand why people down vote without justifying what they see wrong. This is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: I agree. It would be a good idea to force an explanation comment on each downvote

Comment: @Banana I feel they went down this whole thread and down voted everything. Everyone's was down 1 after that. wow.  +1 to your as well.